# sql запрос с двумя таблицами

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

MySql
Есть две таблицы:

table1 с полями id integer primary key, field - varchar(20) not null .

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` 
( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  field VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

table2 с полями t1_id integer not null, table2_field varchar(20) not null.

```
CREATE TABLE `table2`
(t1_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
table2_field VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES table1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Заносим данные:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (1,'table1_field1');
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (2,'table1_field2');

INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES (1,'table2_field');
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.field, t2.`table2_field` from `table1` t1 

LEFT JOIN `table2` t2 

ON t1.id = t2.`t1_id`  ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Получается вот такой результат:

```
id     field            table2_field

1    table1_field1      table2_field
2    table1_field2      NULL
```

Как нужно сформировать запрос , чтобы получить

```
id     field            table2_field

1    table1_field1      table2_field
2    table1_field2      "Пусто"
```

т.е чтобы слово добавить "Пусто" вместо NULL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.field, COALESCE(t2.`table2_field`,'"Пусто"')
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

Для Oracle, если вдруг..)

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.field, NVL(t2.`table2_field`, 'Пусто') from `table1` t1 
LEFT JOIN `table2` t2 
ON t1.id = t2.`t1_id`  ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Comment: за Oracle тоже спасибо, пригодится на будущее)